# Failure of browser windows

Tags: system-installation, kubuntu, firefox, browser, opera

I installed Kubuntu 22.04 LTS on an Asus VivoBook, but when I open the Opera or FireFox browser, it comes out pixelated and not visible.[image: screenshot]